# How to set dynamic query string in App Clip invocation url?

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

I would like to use App Clips with dynamic query string parameters. My url looks like this: [https://example.com/pay?id=[dynamic_guid]](https://example.com/pay?id=%5Bdynamic_guid%5D)

I have already tried to set the invocation url to https://example.com/pay but it's not working if I put the query string into the url.

Can I use a wildcard or it is working only with static urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is case sensitive…
Now it is working fine with /Pay in my case because I set the invocation url with /Pay path.